# SystemExit in Sphinx inheritance diagram

Tags: python, centos, python-sphinx

I am using the `sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram` extension in 1.1.3. However, as soon as I use it, I get this error:

```
SystemExit: error: build/sphinx/html/_images/inheritance2ad9c8a6e9142b91661217c79558016bc8c9ffc7.png.map: No such file or directory
```

The code was moved from a Fedora machine to a centos machine and otherwise works fine aprat from this error which stops Sphinx from building the documentation. Both machine have Sphinx 1.1.3 installed from the main repository.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a [bug in 1.1.3](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/1131/inheritance-diagram-graphviz-issue). Updating to Sphinx 1.2.3 and the bug does not appear anymore.  I am still confused why it worked before but suspect a graphviz issue.